# Sticky navigation & hover on divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to jQuery and JS overall, so please be kind:)

I have a sticky nav bar at the top of my page, which links to various content sections (page locations) beneath. 
The effect I'd like to achieve is for the relevant section to automatically highlight as the user starts to read it (even if they scroll to it manually rather than clicking the link).

Here's an example of what I'm talking about (*notice the nav bar how the divs change when you scroll over the page it's associated with): http://www.domo.com/.

I'm using the jQuery sticky plugin right now to get the menu to stick to the top, but can't figure out how to do the hover.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've seen worse written questions - at least an example is provided.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the problem comes in two parts:

**1. Where on the page are each of my sections?**

In order to highlight a navigation element for each section, you first need to know where each section is.

I suggest using a class like `.section` to define your sections and a `name` attribute to work out which is which, so your markup would look something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>...etc.</head>
  <body>

    <ul>
      <li class="nav" id="nav_one">1</li>
      <li class="nav" id="nav_two">2</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="section" name="one"> Section one</div>

    <div class="section" name="two"> Section two</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript to find where each of the sections is:

```
//define a sections object
var sections = {}

//find all sections on the page, then for each:
$('.section').each(function(){
  //add a property to the object with a key corresponding to the name
  //and a value corresponding to the offset from the top of the page.
  sections[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).offset().top;
});
```

**2. Where on the page is the user?**

The second part of the puzzle is to find which sections are in view. This changes as the user scrolls, so as you might expect, you need to use jQuery's `scroll()` event handler:

```
//the function passed as an argument will be called every time the user scrolls.
$(document).scroll(function(){
  //get the new position
  var newPos = $(this).scrollTop();

  //configurable variable to decide how close a new section needs to be to the
  //top of the page before it's considered the active one.
  var OFFSET = 100;

  //look at all the sections you have, and work out which one should be
  //considered active.
  for(name in sections){
    if(sections[name] > newPos && sections[name] < newPos + OFFSET){
      //the section with name = name is within OFFSET of the top

      //remove "active" styling from the previously active nav elements
      $('.nav').removeClass('active');

      //make the nav element with an id of nav_sectionname active.
      $('#nav_' + name).addClass('active'); 
    }
  }
});
```

**[Codepen example here](http://codepen.io/redders6600/pen/HdkFC)**

Comment: Why not simply use HTML5 sections? `.nav` isn't necessary either. Wrap the menu in `nav` and select the menu elements accordingly.

Comment: Yep, you could do that for some more semantic meaning. The question is more about the implementation of the JavaScript than the html, though. I think my answer gives enough of an idea of how to tackle that part.

Comment: It does. I was just pointing out small points for improvement.

Answer (score 0):

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorials/create-a-sticky-navigation-header-using-jquery-waypoints/

Good tutorial here using jQUery Waypoints.